# Populate Data Table in any wpf control

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, dataset

The reason why I am having a hard time populating this table is because the table get's created dynamically:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader selection = mySql.QuerySelect(textBox1.Text);  //textBox1.Text containts the text of the query to be executed

DataTable table = new DataTable();  // create table to hold results

// depending on the query construct the needed columns
for (int i = 0; i < selection.FieldCount; i++)
{
    table.Columns.Add("Column " + i);
}

// while there are rows insert them
while (selection.Read())
{
    object[] o = new object[selection.FieldCount];
    for(int j=0; j<selection.FieldCount; j++)
    {
        o[j] = selection[j].ToString();
    }
    table.Rows.Add(o);
}
```

ok so far after this point my table is constructed.

### now my problem is how can I display that table so that user can see the results.

here are the things I have tried:

### with a datagrid:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="73,264,17,12" Name="dataGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

code behind:

```
dataGrid1.DataContext = table.DefaultView;
```

that does not display the results. the rows get populated and rows two but with no content...

### with ListView

```
<ListView Height="72" Margin="78,253,17,0" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

code behind:

```
            listView1.DataContext = table.DataSet;
            listView1.DataContext = table.DefaultView;
```

[image]

note the correct number of rows are displayed but with the wrong content.

### with a ListBox

similar technique....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want columns in your grid, so you probably don't want `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`.

To use a `<ListView>`, you'll need to make columns yourself in a `<GridView>`.

To use a `<ListBox>`, set `DisplayTemplate` to a `<DataTemplate>` containing UI for the listboxes.

Comment: Sorry; you need a `DisplayTemplate`.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `ListBox` you need to set the `ItemTemplate` for the listbox. The `ItemTemplate` tells the control how to render each data item (a `DataRowView` from the table's default view).

A simple `DataTemplate` would be a text block with its text property bound to one of the column's in your table

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyTable.DefaultView}">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeColumn}" />
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I need to use whatever. A listbox will be fine. I dont really understand what you mean with the ItemTemplate. recall that I do not know how many columns will the table contain...

Comment: If the table is dynamic then you should use a DataGrid and set AutoGenerateColumns=True -- it will then dynamically create columns for each DataColumn in your table